# ImageView static height, dynamic width

Tags: android, imageview

Thanks to this site, I successfully implemented a Horizontal ListView of ImageViews.
Now what I need is for the ImageViews in the list to have a fixed height (they're part of a more complex layout, so I'm using the LinearLayout weight trick to give it a height equal to 1/3 of the screen height), and a width that adjusts in relation to the height without destroying aspect ratio. The images have a longer height than width - an aspect ratio similar to a phone on portrait.

Now I've tried setting the scaleType to the different available settings, also set adjustViewBounds to true, and set the layout_width to wrap_content and layout_height to fill_parent. The nearest I got to doing it was this:

http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/1289/device20120831133004.png
(i placed the white borders as image background)

What else can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that your `ImageView` cannot be adjusted to desired height because it's aspect ratio is different from screen. Your view matching screen height (or 1/3 of it) and width cannot be scaled proportionally without crop.

Try to set `scaleType` to `centerCrop` and load images **resized** to desired height.

Comment: the aspect ratio of the image vs the screen shouldn't matter, i just gave it as an example to visualize easier. what i want is for the ImageView to adjust its height to fill the space allotted, and adjust the width as needed by the image so as to fill the ImageView without cropping or having unused space on the sides/top and bottom.

Comment: @JosephusVillarey looks like what you're really want is that image will fill parent's **width**. Because there is no simple way to "fill height in one case and not fill in another".

Comment: actually i want the opposite - i want the ImageView's width to "wrap" around the image as fit, while filling the parent's height.

Comment: @JosephusVillarey you need to fit image inside ImageView so it'll have some fixed height and width will be scaled proportionally to fit available space without cropping or empty spaces. Am I right?

Comment: @JosephusVillarey unfortunatelly, I'm still don't get how it's even possible :) If your ImageView is 100x200 and your image is 400x200, how will you scale (let's don't think about programming now, just theory) it?

Comment: the ImageView will adjust to the image, but will need to adjust its height to fill the allotted space first. So for example the height allotted is around 200px, ImageView height should be 200px, image height follows accordingly so height=200px, and by calculating with aspect ratio in mind, width = 100. ImageView will then adjust to wrap the width so imageview width will also be 100. This way there is no distortion of aspect ratio.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16174/discussion-between-dmitry-zaitsev-and-josephus-villarey)